# alright this is weird Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so ok i was just using TKInter when i got this error  NameError
name 'runApps' is not defined

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os 

root = tk.Tk()
apps = []
def addApp():

for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
filetypes=(("executables","*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))
apps.append(filename)
print(filename)
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
    label.pack()


    def runApps():
        for app in apps:
            os.startfile(app)




 canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#163542")
 canvas.pack()

 frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame.place(relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.4, relx=0.3, rely=0.25)

 openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10,
 pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542" ,command=addApp)

 openFile.pack()

 runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10,
 pady=5 , fg="white", bg="#163542" , command = runApps)

 runApps.pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

ok if anyone knows how to fix this make a comment or answer
this section for this post is only for ShanyeLoyd
here is the post you wanted ShanyeLoyd

Comment: Please properly format your code. There are weird indents all over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the indents in your code then it works.

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
> line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
> turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

**Correct formatted code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
apps = []


def addApp():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/",
        title="Select File",
        filetypes=(("executables", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")),
    )
    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()


def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#163542")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame.place(relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.4, relx=0.3, rely=0.25)

openFile = tk.Button(
    root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542", command=addApp
)

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(
    root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#163542", command=runApps
)

runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed. Also, this solution has both a function and a variable named `runApps` which makes the code a bit confusing to read and could yield unexpected behavior as the program evolves.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Thanks for your notice. As I mentioned in my answer, I didn't make any functionality change. I have only fixed the indents. But I have extended my answer perhaps it can help others.